# django sites framework custom settings for each site

Tags: django

How can i extend `django sites framework`?

I need to add more fields, like logo file, subtitle, etc.

Or any other solution for this kind of thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just make `OneToOne` Relation with Site Model

```
from django.contrib.sites.models import Site

class CustomSite(models.Model):
   class Meta:
       verbose_name = "Custom Domain"
       verbose_name_plural = "Custom Domains"
   site = models.OneToOneField(Site, null=True, related_name='customsite')
   subtitle = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   #...
   #...
   def __unicode__(self):
       return 'Customsite of {0}'.format(self.site.domain)
```